# How do I make a query that finds records containing fields, of which the value is contained in other entries?

Tags: sql, ms-access

For example, given a table Cust, containing a field *name*, values of name might be "aabb", "bb", "cc". I would like to make a query, which in this instance would return the records for the first two. What I've tried is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AA.*
FROM (SELECT A.*,IIF(B.ID="","","Dup") DUP
    FROM Cust A LEFT JOIN Cust B ON a.ID <> b.ID 
    AND IF(LENGTH(A.name)>LENGTH(B.name),
    INSTR(A.name,B.name)>0,
    INSTR(B.name,A.name)>0)
)  AS AA;
```

I haven't quite got the hang of SQL yet so I'm struggling to make this work... The error I get at the moment is `Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression 'IIF(B.ID = "", "", "Dup") DUP'`

Comment: I've posted an answer to your syntax error problem, but I don't quite get what your question title is referring to. If the syntax error fix doesn't solve the whole problem, perhaps you can elaborate a bit about what you want the query to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should be using `LIKE`:

```
select t1.name, t2.name
from table1 as t1
inner join table1 as t2
ON t1.name like '%'+t2.name+'%'
AND t1.name <> t2.name
```

See example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3af5b/4

Comment: Please note that the wild card used when running a query in MS Access itself is usually an asterisk (*) not percent (%)

Comment: In addition, using plus (+) to concatenate can cause problems, the usual concatenator in MS Access is ampersand (&)

Comment: Could you use the `InStr()` function to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 IIF(B.ID="","","Dup") DUP
```

to

```
 IIF(B.ID="","","Dup") as DUP
```

Access SQL requires the `AS` keyword when you alias a field.

Also, it looks like you're spelling `IIF` as `IF` in your `WHERE` clause.  That will also result in a syntax error.